# Is there a way to transfer Stack Overflow points (reputation)?

Tags: support, reputation

Can I transfer Stack Overflow's Points to people who help me out?

I currently have 13 points. Would like to sent it to the people who help me out.

Comment: [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how points work.

Comment: You can (sort of) transfer reputation by [offering bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your questions.

Comment: @AlexHowansky But he'll need more than 13 reps before he can offer a bounty.

Comment: People who help you out are already given points. They get points when you accept the answer, and they get points when people upvote their answer.

Comment: Given you have 15+ points now, you can cast upvotes. Each upvote carries 10 points. So every time you find a question or answer helpful, just remember to upvote it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way you can accomplish this is through [offered bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), but they require a **minimum** of [75 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to create.

Comment: Won't it trigger attention of moderator?

Answer (score 7):

No, you may not transfer reputation. Reputation is a measure of how much the community trusts you and your contributions. It's not a "currency" so to speak.

Check [What's Reputation - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

If you wan't to acknowledge the help given to you by others, upvote their answers when they are good for you, mark them as "best answer" if you get many and one of them stands out, etc. That will raise their reputation, which is the reward you're looking to provide

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? No measure will be exact, but reputation acts as a rough measure (stackoverflow's words, not mine). Sure, setting bounties will reduce your reputation score, but by the time you have enough reputation for setting bounties, actually doing so will not reduce your rep so much as to make you look "untrusted"

Comment: @JavierLarroulet strictly speaking you can (and it done on purpose by at least one person) to give out bounties till you lose at least some privileges. I don't think anyone gone all the way to 5 points from 20K+ but there is no restrictions against that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct... I was thinking of a one-time thing :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've seen people go from over 20k to less than 200.  I haven't seen anyone go as low as 5, but it's of course possible to get all the way back to 1 rep if you work everything out just right.

Comment: well, I think we can all agree that even though this is possible/feasible via bounties, it's more the exception than the rule since besides bounties (which are set ex-ante and not ex-post), there's no "reputation transfer" per se

Answer (score 1):

I sense a different and perfectly harmless question in the background, which might be answered by   https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

(There are other possible, and more harmful, questions imaginable, which should be answered by
"Do not do with two accounts anything you cannot do with a single one".
but I do not suspect you of anything in that area.)

Background for my feeling that there might be a different hidden question
(already mentioned in comments by e.g. Barmar, Nisargh Shah and the other answers):
Why do you want to give points by loosing your own? I ask this because even with your now increased sum (19 at the time of me typing this), a single answer, upvoted and accepted by you) gives the answerer more points than you have and you keep yours to be able to do it for the next one again. Almost the same is true for any number of answers on others questions, 10 rep for an upvote.
Even before (the privilege to upvote) accepting an answer "creates" (in contrast to "sacrifices") more points than you have.
Hence my question "Why?" and my feeling.